# Remove multiple duplicate characters from string

Tags: php, string

I have strings like this one:

```
$str = 'This -----is a bbbb test';
```

How can I remove all duplicate characters if it occurs more than 3 times?

So, for example, the string above must look as follows:

```
'This is a  test';
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this using [regular expressions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pcre.php) and [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/preg_replace):

```
$new_str = preg_replace('/(.)\1{3,}/', '', $str);
```

Comment: Hm, this doesn't work. I use different regex which does the trick: preg_replace('{([^\w])\1+}','',$str);

Answer (score 1):

```
$t = preg_replace('/(\S)\1{3,}/', '', $t);
```

Every *non-space* longer than 3 chars will be replaced with *nothing*